# Selecting parent item using css

Tags: html, css

Is there a way that I can select parent item using css? I mean my structure is this

```
<label>
  <input />
<label>
```

In my css I am trying to do something like this,

```
input['_type_']:checked _parent_ label:after{
  some css
}
```

I cannot use, attribute *for* in label.

Comment: **Moderator note**: Please keep comments civil and constructive - thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no parent selector in CSS but you can put `label` after `input` and do something like this (using the adjacent sibling combinator, "`+`", in your selector).

HMTL:

```
<input />
<label><label>
```

CSS:

```
input['_type_']:checked + label:after{ /*means the element that follows input*/
    some css
}
```

You can also do some ugly hacky trick and put another label inside your label

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Konrud/bg0jbear/)

HTML:

```
<label>
  click me
    <input type="checkbox"  />
  <label>color</label>
</label>
```

CSS:

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    color: red;
}
```

This way you can click label and do some stuff with another label that goes after the input.

HTH.

Comment: but doing it like this won't check the input element when the label is clicked. Because it is not associated with any input element.

Comment: You can do some hacky trick (if you cannot using `for` attribute) and put another label inside you label like in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/Konrud/bg0jbear/

Comment: thanks a lot. But I ended up making a custom binder as I am using knockout. It worked for me and the code was not ugly as I would except it to be if using jquery.